# Tkinkter no accepting country code properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making this college project using `tkinter` GUI and `pywhatkit`. It's showing Country code missing even if I put it (with symbol).
My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pywhatkit as kit
import tkinter.messagebox as tmsg
root = Tk()

root.title("Whatsapp Auto Message Scheduler")

p_num = str(Label(root, text = 'Enter the phone number(with Country code):').grid(row = 0))
msg = Label(root, text = 'The message:').grid(row = 1)
h = Label(root, text = 'Timing(hour, as per 24hr clock):').grid(row = 2)
m = Label(root,text = 'Timing(minute):').grid(row = 3)

e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)
e3 = Entry(root)
e4 = Entry(root)

e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
e2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
e3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
e4.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

def pywhatkit():
    p = kit.sendwhatmsg(p_num, msg, h, m)
    tmsg.showinfo("Whatsapp Auto Mesage Scheduler","Response Submitted!")
    return p
B = Button(root, text = 'Submit', command = pywhatkit)

B.grid(row=4,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

The error it's showing:

[image: 1]

Comment: what do You think is `p_num`, I can tell You already it is `"None"` and so is `msg` and so is `h` and so is `m`. why are You using Labels as arguments anyways (not really labels but... `None`, because layout methods return `None`). did You mean to use what is entered in the entries? then You should use `e1.get()`, `e2.get()` and so on

Comment: yes i am trying to do that

Comment: @AryanSingh use `e1.get()`, `e2.get()`, ... instead of `p_num, msg, h, m` inside `kit.sendwhatmsg()`

Comment: also why use `return p` in the `pywhatkit` function? it cannot be accessed anyways since it is called from the button

Comment: it's still shwoing the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Have you actually checked to see what `p_num = str(Label(...))` is? Let's try it in the shell:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> str(tkinter.Label(text="Hello world").grid(row=0))
'None'
>>>
```

I won't get really into it, but the correct way of getting a user's entry is by invoking `.get()` on the associated entry widget:

```
Label(root, text = 'Enter the phone number(with Country code):').grid(row = 0)
Label(root, text = 'The message:').grid(row = 1)
Label(root, text = 'Timing(hour, as per 24hr clock):').grid(row = 2)
Label(root, text = 'Timing(minute):').grid(row = 3)

phone_number_entry = Entry(root)
message_entry = Entry(root)
hour_entry = Entry(root)
minute_entry = Entry(root)

phone_number_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
message_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
hour_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
minute_entry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

def pywhatkit():
    phone_number = phone_number_entry.get()
    message = message_entry.get()
    hour = int(hour_entry.get())
    minute = int(minute_entry.get())
    kit.sendwhatmsg(phone_number, message, hour, minute)
    tmsg.showinfo("Whatsapp Auto Mesage Scheduler","Response Submitted!")
```

Comment: @AryanSingh ~ Consider marking this as the correct answer if this answered your question correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D